# Can't install or boot Linux at all due to GPU error

Tags: boot, radeon, gpu-driver

I have hp envy 1214tx with Intel and AMD GPUs. I was using Ubuntu on it since 4 years. I updated it regularly and was on 16.04 last time.
Everything was working fine until one day it just stopped booting. Booting into it just landed a black screen. So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. 
When I boot using a flash drive I get the error
"radeon: ring 3 test failed"
And it gets stuck there. I tried booting with 14.04, 15.10 and getting same error. 
Even Fedora installation is leading to the same error.
I can't figure out what's wrong with my system as all these distros worked fine since years. 
Can this be a hardware issue?

Comment: This is a well reported bug https://www.google.co.uk/?client=ubuntu#channel=fs&q=%22radeon%3A+ring+3+test+failed%22&gfe_rd=cr you should report it on the Launchpad result.

Comment: Is there anything I can do now?  I am using all these distros since years but none of them just won't boot at all now. It's very frustrating. :(

Comment: Sorry IDK, you will have to wait for an answer, I don't have this type of Hardware around, so I can't do much.

Comment: Have you tried booting 14.04.01 (I mean any older version than 14.04.05 from here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/). It seams strange that such a bug would affect so many distros.